# How to use dynamic Linq with List object

Tags: c#, linq

I have List object of type dynamic like `List<dynamic>` but when I try to use it with Linq then it's not working. Below is my Linq syntax

```cs
var tt = lst.Where(x => (string)x.Type == "test");
```

So how can I use dynamic Linq on List having type as dynamic object.

It throws an error:

> `'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'` does not contain a definition for `'Type'`

Comment: What's your expect result or what did you want to get?

Comment: I want to filter data having Type="test"

Comment: So your `x` is a `List<object>` which doesn't have a `Type` property. Do you expect `x` to be something else maybe?

Comment: You are assuming that x is a string. Why when you declared it as dynamic? See Abdullah Rana's answer below, it makes no assumptions and it works.

Comment: Can't be answered without knowing what `lst` is. Please turn this into a [mre]. It seems that `lst` is a list of lists of type `List<object>`. Such details matter.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have declared the dynamic type correctly or is there any mismatch between the objects. I just tried the same thing and it works for me.

```
dynamic obj = new {
    Data = "sjds"
};

dynamic obj2 = new {
    Data = "sjdsf"
};

List<dynamic> dynamics = new List<dynamic>();
dynamics.Add(obj);
dynamics.Add(obj2);

var str = dynamics.Where(x => x.Data == "sjds");
```

If your case different than this you can share the full code to better understand the scenario.

Comment: I don't think that's what's going on here. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has no way to know what your `dynamic` objects look like. Therefore you need to tell the compiler by casting to a type. Since you're assuming that a particular property exists on your dynamic object (`Type`), you can try and cast it.

```
List<YourType> yourList = lst as List<YourType>;
if (yourList!=null){
  var filtereList = yourList.Where(x=>x.Type.Equals("test"));
}
```